# Dealing with Local Branches and Remote Branches In Git

Tags: git, github, version-control, merge, git-branch

I am a beginner to Git.I am dealing with 10 branches like **BR-1, BR-2.....BR-10 and one Dev Branch and One Master Branch**. I am working with one of the branch like BR-10.

**1.** **Question-1 :**

Now after making lot of changes and adding new files to BR-10 what should I do for a safe commit to the branch BR-10 ?

**2.** **Question-2 :**

After committing how can I add this local branch into the remote dev branch ( I mean how to raise a pull request to add this branch to the Remote Dev branch ) ? ["please explain a bit, about from which branch I have to execute the commit commands, push commands and pull request)

**3. Question-3**

I don't know am I supposed to ask this that, can anyone please explain from creating branches, working on a particular branch, committing those changes, pushing it into remote repository, and how to give pull request to remote branches not to the master branch.

Answer (score 0):

After Making all your changes to your BR-10 Branch.

Commit your changes to BR10 local branch

using

```
git add .
git commit -m "your git message"
```

Once doing that Push your local BR-10 Branch to your remote server.

```
git push origin BR-10
```

Once done you have to generate a PR for merging your code from BR-10 branch to dev branch

For doing so

Just select a BR-10 branch in your server and on right side you will find a button for generate PR.

Select your branch and dev branch there and generate PR

Comment: Thanks Alok, this helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

To create the git repository you go to the folder with your project files in terminal and use the command

```
git init name_of_repository
```

Then you add files now or as you make them

```
git add file_name
```

After finishing a feature in a file, you commit it

```
git commit -a -m "Description"
```

This command is perfectly safe if you have made a lot of changes, after that the you use the push command

```
git push origin branch_name
```

This command will push to origin (the repository you cloned from), if you don't want to push to that repository you will have to make a different repository a remote

```
git push remote_name branch_name
```

to make a clone you use this command

```
git clone file_path_to_repository_you're_cloning clone_name
```

Then to make a repository the remote of another you use this command:

```
git remote add name_of_repository file_path_to_repository
```

To pull from a different repository you use this command

```
git pull repository_to_pull_from branch_to_pull_from
```